# Admob banner visible in preview mode, but not when running

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Im trying to add a banner to my Android application, but can't get it to work. The banner is visible in the preview but not when running on my Genymotion device. This is my layout-file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.my.package.MapsActivity"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dip"
    tools:context="com.example.my.package.MapsActivity"/>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the Activity-file I have this code:

```
MobileAds.initialize(mContext, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx");
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

It does not work with test ads either. What can be wrong?

Hank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I would like to say that whenever you create a banner or interstitial than you have to wait for few hours for ads to display on your mobile screen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your gmail account used in the Genymotion is the same with admob account. Try change to another gmail in your Genymotion.